# persian-date-picker in Umbraco(cms of asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, umbraco, datetimepicker

i need to add a persian (shamsi) date time picker in my website and I have already asked my problem in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429558/how-do-i-add-a-persian-or-other-language-datatimepicker-in-umbraco/13436513#comment18375515_13436513).

And -codegecko wrote a true answer for me.
-codegecko answer's:
You can create new data-types in Umbraco to both store and render dates in your own style and preference. The process involves creating a couple of classes, one of which implements an interface called IDataType. Tim Geyssens, staff at Umbraco HQ, has a great blogpost on the basics [here](http://www.nibble.be/?p=50).

As a result, I'm trying to do so. I downloaded different versions of date-persian-picker control written for Asp.Net and changed -codegecko's code to work with date-persian picker:

```
private persianDatePicker pdate;
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
 {
  pdate = new persianDatePicker();
  base.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(pdate); 
 }
```

when I add it in Umbraco, I saw an empty box without any dates in it in content box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked same as you and I satisfied.
I think you must check `persianDatePicker`.

Please use [this link](http://s3.picofile.com/file/7561800000/DatePersianPicker.rar.html)